# Writing data to MYSQL database from python not persistent

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Forgive my ignorance.  I'm a rookie trying to learn some programming.

I have the following code implemented in Visual Studio 2010:

```
def print_tmpsalary():
import sys
import MySQLdb
FD_playerpicker = []
FD_playerpicker = {"8595":["C","Evgeni Malkin","51189","672","2","9600",6.1,"75",False,4,""],"8472":["G","Pekka Rinne","51188","665","15","9400",5.7,"73",False,4,""],"8594":["C","Sidney Crosby","51189","672","5","9300",6.2,"22",False,0,""],"8173":["G","Johan Hedberg","51190","666","1000","8800",5.5,"27",False,0,""],"8592":["G","Ilya Bryzgalov","51189","670","1000","8700",4.8,"59",False,4,""],"8712":["G","Roberto Luongo","51191","677","25","8700",5.4,"55",False,4,""],"8492":["G","Martin Brodeur","51190","666","12","8400",4.4,"59",False,4,""],"8412":["G","Jon Quick","51191","662","1000","8400",5.4,"69",False,4,""],"8612":["G","Marc-Andre Fleury","51189","672","71","8300",5.1,"67",False,4,""],"8781":["G","Cory Schneider","51191","677","1000","8300",6.2,"33",False,0,""],"8353":["G","Jimmy Howard","51188","659","1000","8300",5.4,"57",False,4,""],"8319":["RW","James Neal","51189","672","1000","8200",4.7,"80",False,0,""],"8158":["RW","Ilya Kovalchuk","51190","666","45","8200",4.4,"77",False,4,""],"8253":["G","Michael Leighton","51189","670","1000","8200",6.4,"1",False,0,""],"8556":["C","Claude Giroux","51189","670","120","8000",4.5,"77",False,0,""],"8698":["LW","Daniel Sedin","51191","677","24","7800",4.1,"72",False,0,""],"8393":["G","Scott Clemmensen","51190","661","1000","7700",4.4,"30",False,0,""],"8394":["C","Anze Kopitar","51191","662","1000","7300",3.6,"82",False,4,""],"8608":["D","Kris Letang","51189","672","1000","7200",3.7,"51",False,4,""],"8733":["G","Jose Theodore","51190","661","1000","7200",4.6,"53",False,4,""],"12283":["G","Jacob Markstrom","51190","661","1000","7100",4.6,"7",False,0,""],"8555":["C","Jeff Carter","51191","662","8","7100",2.9,"55",False,0,""],"8478":["LW","Zach Parise","51190","666","6","7000",3.6,"82",False,0,""],"8598":["LW","Chris Kunitz","51189","672","79","7000",3.4,"82",False,0,""],"8335":["C","Henrik Zetterberg","51188","659","13","7000",3.7,"82",False,4,""],"8334":["LW","Pavel Datsyuk","51188","659","3","7000",3.6,"70",False,4,""],"8563":["C","Danny Briere","51189","670","102","6900",3.1,"70",False,0,""],"8703":["RW","Alex Burrows","51191","677","31","6900",3.3,"80",False,4,""],"8694":["C","Henrik Sedin","51191","677","61","6900",3.3,"82",False,4,""],"8562":["LW","Scott Hartnell","51189","670","32","6800",4,"82",False,4,""],"8403":["RW","Justin Williams","51191","662","1000","6800",3.3,"82",False,0,""],"8402":["RW","Dustin Brown","51191","662","1000","6800",3.1,"82",False,4,""],"8554":["C","Mike Richards","51191","662","30","6700",2.7,"74",False,0,""],"12163":["G","Sergei Bobrovsky","51189","670","1000","6700",4,"29",False,0,""],"8765":["RW","Patric Hornqvist","51188","665","1000","6700",3,"76",False,0,""],"8484":["RW","David Clarkson","51190","666","97","6700",3.1,"80",False,0,""],"8474":["C","Patrik Elias","51190","666","51","6700",3.2,"81",False,0,""],"8596":["C","Jordan Staal","51189","672","176","6700",3.3,"62",False,0,""],"8613":["G","Brent Johnson","51189","672","1000","6600",2.8,"16",False,0,""],"8702":["C","Ryan Kesler","51191","677","134","6600",3.2,"77",False,0,""],"8970":["G","Joey MacDonald","51188","659","1000","6500",4.5,"14",False,0,""],"8601":["RW","Pascal Dupuis","51189","672","1000","6500",3.1,"82",False,4,""],"8780":["G","Jonathan Bernier","51191","662","1000","6500",3.5,"16",False,0,""],"8338":["RW","Johan Franzen","51188","659","36","6500",3.4,"77",False,0,""],"8462":["RW","Martin Erat","51188","665","1000","6400",2.9,"71",False,0,""],"8260":["RW","Kris Versteeg","51190","661","158","6400",3.2,"71",False,0,""],"8566":["D","Chris Pronger","51189","670","57","6400",3.2,"13",False,2,"Concussion, knee surgery"],"8845":["G","Brad Thiessen","51189","672","1000","6400",3.1,"5",False,0,""],"8653":["G","Ty Conklin","51188","659","193","6300",3,"15",False,0,""],"14561":["RW","Jaromir Jagr","51189","670","1000","6300",3,"73",False,0,""],"8604":["LW","Tyler Kennedy","51189","672","148","6300",2.9,"60",False,0,""],"8467":["D","Shea Weber","51188","665","157","6300",3.2,"78",False,0,""],"8704":["RW","Mikael Samuelsson","51190","661","117","6200",2.7,"54",False,0,""],"8404":["LW","Wayne Simmonds","51189","670","1000","6200",2.9,"82",False,0,""],"8535":["C","Mike Fisher","51188","665","1000","6200",3,"72",False,0,""],"8797":["LW","James van Riemsdyk","51189","670","1000","6200",2.7,"43",False,2,"Broken left foot"],"8303":["RW","Jakub Voracek","51189","670","124","6200",2.8,"78",False,4,""],"8720":["LW","Tomas Fleischmann","51190","661","1000","6100",3,"82",False,4,""],"8336":["C","Valtteri Filppula","51188","659","1000","6000",3,"81",False,0,""],"8455":["C","David Legwand","51188","665","1000","6000",2.6,"78",False,4,""],"8558":["LW","Simon Gagne","51191","662","69","6000",2.3,"34",False,2,"Upper-body injury"],"12252":["G","Anders Lindback","51188","665","1000","5900",3.4,"16",False,0,""],"8374":["C","Stephen Weiss","51190","661","131","5900",2.8,"80",False,0,""],"8463":["LW","Steve Sullivan","51189","672","1000","5800",2.3,"79",False,0,""],"8709":["D","Alexander Edler","51191","677","147","5800",2.7,"82",False,4,""],"8711":["D","Kevin Bieksa","51191","677","130","5700",2.6,"78",False,0,""],"13932":["RW","Matt Read","51189","670","1000","5700",2.6,"79",False,0,""],"8799":["LW","Petr Sykora","51190","666","1000","5700",2.4,"82",False,4,""],"8355":["C","Mike Comrie","51189","672","1000","5700",1.2,"21",False,0,""],"21546":["RW","Alexander Radulov","51188","665","1000","5600",3.3,"9",False,4,""],"8378":["LW","David Booth","51191","677","38","5600",2.4,"62",False,0,""],"8518":["LW","Christopher Higgins","51191","677","1000","5600",2.7,"71",False,0,""],"8406":["D","Drew Doughty","51191","662","1000","5600",2.2,"77",False,4,""],"8499":["LW","Sean Bergenheim","51190","661","1000","5500",2.4,"62",False,0,""],"15239":["C","Craig Smith","51188","665","1000","5500",2.2,"72",False,0,""],"8466":["D","Ryan Suter","51188","665","198","5500",2.4,"79",False,4,""],"8346":["D","Nicklas Lidstrom","51188","659","26","5500",2.5,"70",False,4,""],"8475":["C","Travis Zajac","51190","666","75","5500",1.5,"15",False,0,""],"12843":["C","Adam Henrique","51190","666","1000","5500",2.5,"74",False,0,""],"8342":["RW","Daniel Cleary","51188","659","1000","5500",2.2,"75",False,0,""],"8443":["RW","Andrei Kostitsyn","51188","665","142","5400",2,"72",False,0,""],"9168":["RW","Todd Bertuzzi","51188","659","1000","5400",2.5,"71",False,4,""],"8268":["D","Brian Campbell","51190","661","173","5400",2.1,"82",False,4,""],"8668":["D","Andrej Meszaros","51189","670","1000","5400",1.9,"62",False,2,"Lower back surgery"],"8444":["LW","Sergei Kostitsyn","51188","665","191","5400",2.2,"75",False,0,""],"12494":["LW","Jiri Hudler","51188","659","1000","5400",2.5,"81",False,0,""],"8468":["D","Dan Hamhuis","51191","677","1000","5400",2.2,"82",False,0,""],"8464":["LW","Colin Wilson","51188","665","1000","5400",2.2,"68",False,0,""],"8877":["D","Jason Garrison","51190","661","1000","5300",2.2,"77",False,0,""],"8811":["RW","Jannik Hansen","51191","677","1000","5300",2.1,"82",False,4,""],"8600":["LW","Matt Cooke","51189","672","1000","5300",2.1,"82",False,0,""],"8568":["D","Kimmo Timonen","51189","670","144","5300",2.3,"76",False,0,""],"8579":["RW","Scottie Upshall","51190","661","1000","5200",1.5,"26",False,0,""],"8736":["G","Manny Legace","51191","677","1000","5200",0,0,False,0,""],"9013":["G","Jason Bacashihua","51189","670","1000","5200",0,0,False,0,""],"8795":["G","Johan Backlund","51189","670","1000","5200",0,0,False,0,""],"8476":["RW","Dainius Zubrus","51190","666","1000","5200",2,"82",False,4,""],"9235":["G","Matt Climie","51191","677","1000","5200",2,"1",False,0,""],"8287":["D","Kyle Quincey","51188","659","1000","5200",2.1,"72",False,0,""],"9440":["LW","Scott Parse","51191","662","1000","5200",1.6,"9",False,2,"Hip surgery"],"8457":["C","Marcel Goc","51190","661","1000","5200",2,"57",False,4,""],"9167":["G","Thomas McCollum","51188","659","1000","5200",-2,"1",False,0,""],"8340":["C","Darren Helm","51188","659","1000","5200",1.7,"68",False,0,""],"11370":["G","Eddie Lack","51191","677","1000","5200",0,0,False,0,""],"8934":["G","Tyler Plante","51190","661","1000","5200",0,0,False,0,""],"8257":["RW","Tomas Kopecky","51190","661","1000","5100",1.7,"80",False,4,""],"8679":["LW","Alexei Ponikarovsky","51190","666","1000","5100",1.8,"82",False,0,""],"8279":["LW","Wojtek Wolski","51190","661","1000","5100",1.4,"31",False,0,""],"8564":["RW","Ian Laperriere","51189","670","1000","5100",0,0,False,2,"Post-concussion syndrome"],"8485":["RW","Nicklas Bergfors","51188","665","1000","5100",0.7,"11",False,0,""],"8691":["D","Ian White","51188","659","1000","5000",2.4,"77",False,0,""],"8707":["D","Sami Salo","51191","677","1000","5000",1.9,"69",False,0,""],"8706":["D","Willie Mitchell","51191","662","1000","5000",1.7,"76",False,0,""],"11240":["LW","Eric Wellwood","51189","670","1000","5000",2.1,"24",False,0,""],"8360":["LW","Dustin Penner","51191","662","1000","5000",1.4,"65",False,0,""],"8700":["LW","Mason Raymond","51191","677","1000","5000",2,"55",False,0,""],"8465":["RW","Jordin Tootoo","51188","665","1000","4900",1.8,"77",False,0,""],"8603":["RW","Max Talbot","51189","670","1000","4900",1.9,"81",False,0,""],"8878":["D","Dmitry Kulikov","51190","661","1000","4900",1.9,"58",False,0,""],"8395":["C","Jarret Stoll","51191","662","1000","4900",1.6,"78",False,0,""],"8348":["D","Niklas Kronwall","51188","659","165","4900",1.9,"82",False,0,""],"8435":["C","Maxim Lapierre","51191","677","1000","4900",1.4,"82",False,0,""],"8365":["RW","Zack Stortini","51188","665","1000","4900",2.2,"1",False,0,""],"9325":["RW","Patrick Eaves","51188","659","1000","4900",1.2,"10",False,2,"Broken jaw"],"8504":["RW","Trent Hunter","51191","662","1000","4800",0.9,"38",False,0,""],"8179":["LW","Marco Sturm","51190","661","145","4800",0.7,"48",False,0,""],"9128":["RW","Brandon Yip","51188","665","1000","4800",1.2,"35",False,0,""],"8375":["C","Steve Reinprecht","51191","677","1000","4800",1.3,"29",False,0,""],"8749":["RW","Matt Halischuk","51188","665","1000","4700",1.7,"73",False,0,""],"8967":["D","Alec Martinez","51191","662","1000","4700",1.3,"51",False,0,""],"8969":["D","Viatcheslav Voynov","51191","662","1000","4700",1.9,"54",False,0,""],"11401":["LW","Gabriel Bourque","51188","665","1000","4700",1.6,"43",False,4,""],"15308":["C","Sean Couturier","51189","670","1000","4700",1.8,"77",False,0,""],"8428":["D","Marek Zidlicky","51190","666","188","4700",1.3,"63",False,4,""],"8196":["C","Paul Gaustad","51188","665","1000","4700",1.4,"70",False,0,""],"8567":["D","Braydon Coburn","51189","670","136","4700",1.5,"81",False,4,""],"8569":["D","Matt Carle","51189","670","1000","4700",1.9,"82",False,0,""],"12259":["D","Brendan Smith","51188","659","1000","4600",1.9,"14",False,0,""],"9145":["D","Ben Lovejoy","51189","672","1000","4600",1.1,"34",False,0,""],"8815":["D","Aaron Rome","51191","677","1000","4600",1.1,"43",False,0,""],"9401":["RW","Brian McGrattan","51188","665","1000","4600",0.7,"30",False,0,""],"8486":["D","Paul Martin","51189","672","113","4600",1.5,"73",False,0,""],"9266":["C","Brayden Schenn","51189","670","1000","4600",1.7,"54",False,4,""],"9218":["C","Mike Santorelli","51190","661","1000","4600",1.2,"60",False,0,""],"8935":["RW","Mike Duco","51191","677","1000","4500",1.3,"6",False,0,""],"8341":["LW","Justin Abdelkader","51188","659","1000","4500",1.5,"81",False,0,""],"12262":["D","Roman Josi","51188","665","1000","4500",1.3,"52",False,0,""],"8561":["RW","Arron Asham","51189","672","1000","4500",1.1,"64",False,4,""],"8587":["D","Zbynek Michalek","51189","672","1000","4500",1.1,"62",False,0,""],"8607":["D","Brooks Orpik","51189","672","1000","4500",1.2,"73",False,0,""],"8343":["RW","Tomas Holmstrom","51188","659","65","4500",1.4,"74",False,0,""],"8879":["C","Shawn Matthias","51190","661","1000","4500",1.6,"79",False,0,""],"8469":["D","Kevin Klein","51188","665","1000","4500",1.2,"66",False,0,""],"10815":["RW","Mark Mancari","51191","677","1000","4400",0.3,"6",False,0,""],"11152":["LW","Zack Kassian","51191","677","1000","4400",1.3,"44",False,0,""],"8397":["LW","Brad Richardson","51191","662","1000","4400",1,"59",False,0,""],"8621":["LW","Jody Shelley","51189","670","1000","4400",0.7,"30",False,0,""],"8359":["LW","Ethan Moreau","51191","662","1000","4400",0.8,"28",False,0,""],"8328":["D","Matt Niskanen","51189","672","1000","4400",1.6,"75",False,0,""],"8511":["D","Jack Hillen","51188","665","1000","4400",0.8,"55",False,0,""],"11237":["C","Zac Rinaldo","51189","670","1000","4400",1.5,"66",False,0,""],"8385":["RW","Michal Repik","51190","661","1000","4400",1.5,"17",False,0,""],"8664":["LW","Drew Miller","51188","659","1000","4400",1.6,"80",False,0,""],"8848":["RW","Chris Conner","51188","659","1000","4300",1.6,"8",False,0,""],"9087":["C","Nick Spaling","51188","665","1000","4300",1.2,"77",False,0,""],"8325":["RW","Krys Barch","51190","661","1000","4300",1,"51",False,0,""],"8181":["RW","Byron Bitz","51191","677","1000","4300",1.7,"10",False,0,""],"9275":["LW","Kyle Clifford","51191","662","1000","4300",1.1,"81",False,0,""],"8409":["D","Matt Greene","51191","662","1000","4300",1,"82",False,0,""],"9299":["RW","Jack Skille","51190","661","1000","4300",1.1,"46",False,0,""],"8872":["D","Alexandre Picard","51189","672","1000","4300",1,"17",False,0,""],"8137":["C","Andrew Ebbett","51191","677","1000","4300",1.8,"18",False,0,""],"8386":["D","Keith Ballard","51191","677","1000","4300",1,"47",False,0,""],"9083":["D","Ryan Ellis","51188","665","1000","4200",1.5,"32",False,0,""],"8296":["C","Samuel Pahlsson","51191","677","1000","4200",1,"80",False,0,""],"8850":["D","Deryk Engelland","51189","672","1000","4200",1.3,"73",False,0,""],"8705":["RW","Steve Bernier","51190","666","1000","4200",1,"32",False,0,""],"8349":["D","Brad Stuart","51188","659","1000","4200",1.4,"81",False,0,""],"8548":["D","Anton Volchenkov","51190","666","1000","4200",0.8,"72",False,0,""],"8166":["D","Pavel Kubina","51189","670","129","4200",1.2,"69",False,0,""],"8671":["D","Matt Walker","51189","670","1000","4100",0.7,"4",False,0,""],"8256":["C","John Madden","51190","661","1000","4100",0.6,"31",False,0,""],"8725":["RW","Matt Bradley","51190","661","1000","4100",0.8,"45",False,2,"Concussion"],"9085":["C","Cal O'Reilly","51189","672","1000","4100",0.4,"33",False,0,""],"9281":["C","Oscar Moller","51191","662","1000","4100",1.5,"13",False,0,""],"8597":["RW","Craig Adams","51189","672","1000","4100",0.9,"82",False,0,""],"8490":["D","Andy Greene","51190","666","1000","4100",1.1,"56",False,0,""],"12192":["C","Jacob Josefson","51190","666","1000","4100",1.1,"41",False,0,""],"9043":["D","Jakub Kindl","51188","659","1000","4100",1.2,"55",False,0,""],"8586":["D","Ed Jovanovski","51190","661","1000","4100",0.8,"66",False,0,""],"8140":["C","Ryan Carter","51190","666","1000","4100",0.7,"72",False,0,""],"8852":["C","Dustin Jeffrey","51189","672","1000","4100",1,"26",False,0,""],"9026":["LW","Steve MacIntyre","51189","672","1000","4000",0.1,"12",False,0,""],"8489":["D","Bryce Salvador","51190","666","1000","4000",0.9,"82",False,0,""],"8161":["LW","Eric Boulton","51190","666","1000","4000",0.5,"51",False,0,""],"8350":["D","Jonathan Ericsson","51188","659","1000","4000",1.1,"69",False,0,""],"8943":["RW","Vladimir Zharkov","51190","666","1000","4000",-0.5,"4",False,0,""],"10883":["D","Matthew Corrente","51190","666","1000","4000",1.2,"22",False,0,""],"8734":["C","Manny Malhotra","51191","677","1000","4000",0.8,"78",False,0,""],"8207":["D","Henrik Tallinder","51190","666","1000","4000",0.6,"39",False,2,"Lower left leg"],"12687":["D","Mark Fayne","51190","666","1000","4000",1,"82",False,0,""],"8966":["C","Trevor Lewis","51191","662","1000","4000",0.9,"72",False,0,""],"8863":["LW","Tom Sestito","51189","670","1000","4000",1.5,"14",False,2,"Torn groin muscle"],"8774":["D","Francis Bouillon","51188","665","1000","4000",0.7,"66",False,0,""],"9008":["D","Marc-Andre Gragnani","51191","677","1000","4000",1.2,"58",False,0,""],"8645":["RW","Cam Janssen","51190","666","1000","4000",0.4,"48",False,0,""],"10851":["D","Andreas Lilja","51189","670","1000","3900",0.9,"46",False,0,""],"9341":["D","Jay Leach","51190","666","1000","3900",0.4,"7",False,0,""],"9279":["C","Andrei Loktionov","51191","662","1000","3900",1,"39",False,0,""],"8330":["D","Nicklas Grossman","51189","670","1000","3900",0.8,"74",False,0,""],"11384":["C","Joakim Andersson","51188","659","1000","3900",0.4,"5",False,0,""],"12765":["D","Matt Taormina","51190","666","1000","3900",1.2,"30",False,0,""],"8170":["D","Boris Valabik","51189","672","1000","3900",0,0,False,0,""],"8324":["LW","Fabian Brunnstrom","51188","659","1000","3900",0.7,"5",False,0,""],"8250":["D","Andrew Alberts","51191","677","1000","3900",0.7,"44",False,0,""],"8965":["LW","Dwight King","51191","662","1000","3900",2.1,"27",False,4,""],"8450":["D","Hal Gill","51188","665","1000","3800",0.7,"76",False,0,""],"8756":["C","Colin Fraser","51191","662","1000","3800",0.8,"67",False,0,""],"9267":["RW","Kevin Westgarth","51191","662","1000","3800",0.7,"25",False,0,""],"8197":["C","Adam Mair","51189","670","1000","3800",0.4,"65",False,0,""],"12193":["LW","Mattias Tedenby","51190","666","1000","3800",0.5,"43",False,0,""],"8690":["D","Garnet Exelby","51188","659","1000","3800",0,0,False,0,""],"9277":["D","Peter Harrold","51190","666","1000","3800",0.8,"11",False,0,""],"9115":["D","Tyson Strachan","51190","661","1000","3800",1,"15",False,0,""],"10912":["D","Marc-Andre Bourdon","51189","670","1000","3800",1.2,"45",False,0,""],"8963":["D","Davis Drewiske","51191","662","1000","3800",1.2,"9",False,0,""],"8855":["C","Joe Vitale","51189","672","1000","3800",1,"68",False,0,""],"9023":["D","Tyler Sloan","51188","665","1000","3800",0.5,"33",False,0,""],"9306":["C","Kyle Wilson","51188","665","1000","3700",-0,"5",False,0,""],"8498":["RW","Richard Park","51189","672","1000","3700",1,"54",False,0,""],"9154":["RW","Bill Thomas","51190","661","1000","3700",0.9,"7",False,0,""],"11225":["RW","Dale Weise","51191","677","1000","3700",0.9,"68",False,0,""],"8876":["D","Keaton Ellerby","51190","661","1000","3700",0.7,"40",False,0,""],"8460":["LW","Jerred Smithson","51190","661","1000","3700",0.5,"69",False,0,""],"8881":["RW","Victor Oreskovich","51191","677","1000","3700",1.8,"1",False,0,""],"14564":["D","Adam Larsson","51190","666","1000","3700",1,"65",False,0,""],"9215":["D","Jonathon Blum","51188","665","1000","3700",0.4,"33",False,0,""],"9276":["LW","Richard Clune","51191","662","1000","3700",0,0,False,0,""],"11304":["D","Erik Gustafsson","51189","670","1000","3600",1,"30",False,0,""],"9257":["D","Nolan Baumgartner","51191","677","1000","3600",0,0,False,0,""],"9170":["D","Doug Janik","51188","659","1000","3600",0.9,"9",False,0,""],"9169":["C","Cory Emmerton","51188","659","1000","3500",0.8,"71",False,0,""],"12291":["D","Chris Tanev","51191","677","1000","3500",0.8,"25",False,0,""],"9048":["D","Oskars Bartulis","51189","670","1000","3500",-0,"13",False,0,""],"9172":["LW","Jan Mursak","51188","659","1000","3500",0.7,"25",False,0,""],"9219":["D","Nolan Yonkman","51190","661","1000","3500",0,"1",False,0,""],"9352":["C","Blair Betts","51189","670","1000","3500",0.6,"75",False,2,"Lower-body injury"],"8891":["D","Mike Weaver","51190","661","1000","3500",0.7,"82",False,0,""],"8849":["D","Simon Despres","51189","672","1000","3500",1.4,"18",False,0,""],"9019":["RW","Andrew Gordon","51191","677","1000","3400",0.5,"37",False,0,""],"10965":["RW","Colin McDonald","51189","672","1000","3400",0.5,"5",False,0,""],"11280":["LW","Aaron Volpatti","51191","677","1000","3400",0.7,"23",False,2,"Torn labrum"],"13631":["RW","Harry Zolnierczyk","51189","670","1000","3400",0.9,"37",False,0,""],"9365":["C","Ryan Craig","51189","672","1000","3400",0.9,"6",False,0,""],"8408":["D","Rob Scuderi","51191","662","1000","3400",0.5,"82",False,0,""],"9336":["C","James Wright","51190","661","1000","3400",-2,"1",False,0,""],"8854":["C","Eric Tangradi","51189","672","1000","3400",0.5,"24",False,0,""],"12447":["D","Erik Gudbranson","51190","661","1000","3300",0.7,"72",False,0,""],"8697":["C","Ryan Johnson","51188","659","1000","3300",0.7,"34",False,0,""],"12738":["C","Jordan Nolan","51191","662","1000","3300",1,"26",False,0,""],"8344":["RW","Jason Williams","51189","672","169","3300",1.1,"8",False,0,""],"9321":["C","Tomas Tatar","51188","659","1000","3200",0.6,"9",False,0,""],"12892":["C","Chris Mueller","51188","665","1000","3200",0.2,"4",False,0,""],"13982":["C","Gustav Nyquist","51188","659","1000","3200",1.4,"18",False,0,""],"9021":["RW","Steve Pinizzotto","51191","677","1000","3200",0,0,False,2,"Dislocated shoulder, surgery"],"8942":["D","Alexander Urbom","51190","666","1000","3200",1.5,"5",False,0,""],"10886":["RW","Stephen Gionta","51190","666","1000","3200",4.8,"1",False,0,""],"9343":["C","Tim Sestito","51190","666","1000","3200",-0,"18",False,0,""],"8570":["D","Ryan Parent","51191","677","1000","3200",-0.5,"4",False,0,""],"10889":["C","Brad Mills","51190","666","1000","3200",0.3,"27",False,0,""],"9295":["C","Mark Cullen","51190","661","1000","3100",0.8,"6",False,0,""],"8962":["RW","Marc-Andre Cliche","51191","662","1000","3100",0,0,False,0,""],"11233":["C","Ben Holmstrom","51189","670","1000","3100",0.3,"5",False,0,""],"11008":["D","Anders Eriksson","51191","677","1000","3100",0,0,False,0,""],"10915":["C","Jonathan Matsumoto","51190","661","1000","3100",0,"1",False,0,""],"11204":["D","Jacob Muzzin","51191","662","1000","3100",0.3,"11",False,0,""],"9084":["D","Teemu Laakso","51188","665","1000","3100",0.3,"9",False,0,""],"21921":["C","Riley Sheahan","51188","659","1000","3000",2.2,"1",False,0,""],"8411":["D","Thomas Hickey","51191","662","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"12635":["C","Bracken Kearns","51190","661","1000","3000",0.5,"5",False,0,""],"12714":["C","Ilari Filppula","51188","659","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"14183":["G","Keith Kinkaid","51190","666","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"14456":["D","Mattias Ekholm","51188","665","1000","3000",-0.3,"2",False,0,""],"8424":["RW","Owen Nolan","51191","677","172","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"9402":["C","Steve Zalewski","51190","666","1000","3000",0.1,"7",False,0,""],"8847":["D","Robert Bortuzzo","51189","672","1000","3000",0.5,"6",False,0,""],"9238":["D","Dan Jancevski","51189","670","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"8661":["LW","Todd Fedoruk","51191","677","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"8817":["D","Yann Sauve","51191","677","1000","3000",0.1,"5",False,0,""],"9070":["D","Shaun Heshka","51191","662","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"8177":["C","Steve Begin","51191","677","1000","3000",-0.1,"2",False,0,""],"9057":["G","Timo Pielmeier","51190","666","1000","3000",-3.6,"1",False,0,""],"8924":["LW","Chris Minard","51188","659","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"9300":["LW","Mark Santorelli","51188","665","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"11214":["LW","Ryan Thang","51188","665","1000","3000",0,"1",False,0,""],"11245":["D","Brian Strait","51189","672","1000","3000",0.3,"9",False,0,""],"11386":["D","Carl Sneep","51189","672","1000","3000",3,"1",False,0,""],"10898":["C","Brodie Dupont","51188","665","1000","3000",0.4,"1",False,0,""],"10840":["D","Ray Macias","51191","662","1000","3000",-0.3,"2",False,0,""],"9358":["RW","Stefan Legein","51191","662","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""],"8882":["C","Scott Timmins","51190","661","1000","3000",0.1,"19",False,0,""],"12164":["LW","Andrew Rowe","51189","670","1000","3000",0,0,False,0,""]}

try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(db="FanDueldb",host="localhost",user="root",passwd="password");
    print "Connected<br/>"
except:
    print "Cannot connect to server.</br>"
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for playerdata in FD_playerpicker:
        x = FD_playerpicker[playerdata][0]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `fandueldb`.`tblfdsalarytmp` (PlayerID,Position,Player,Placeholder1,Placeholder2,PlaceHolder3,Salary,PPG,GamesPlayed,PlaceHolder4,PlaceHolder5,PlaceHolder6) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(playerdata,FD_playerpicker[playerdata][0],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][1],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][2],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][3],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][4],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][5],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][6],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][7],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][8],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][9],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][10]))


    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tblFDSalarytmp WHERE RecordID = 1")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for record in result:
        print record[0] , "-->", record[1]

    #cursor.close()
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "query failed<br/>"
    print e

conn.close()
print "Disconnected<br/>"
sys.exit(0)
```

The code runs without error, and I can print out results when debugging the code. But when I open MySQL workbench to view the written data, nothing is there. There is an auto increment field called recordID that has been incremented, so I know the data has "touched" the database, but it's as if it gets deleted once the code stops running.

First time using any such database, I know there's something I'm just not understanding. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe MySQLdb disables autocommit by default. You'll need to call `.commit()` on your connection after all your `INSERT` statements have been executed.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for playerdata in FD_playerpicker:
    x = FD_playerpicker[playerdata][0]
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `fandueldb`.`tblfdsalarytmp` (PlayerID,Position,Player,Placeholder1,Placeholder2,PlaceHolder3,Salary,PPG,GamesPlayed,PlaceHolder4,PlaceHolder5,PlaceHolder6) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(playerdata,FD_playerpicker[playerdata][0],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][1],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][2],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][3],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][4],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][5],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][6],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][7],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][8],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][9],FD_playerpicker[playerdata][10]))

# Commit following all INSERT statements
conn.commit()
```

[From the MySQLdb FAQ:](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html)

> Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables autocommit by default, as required by the DB-API standard (PEP-249). If you are using InnoDB tables or some other type of transactional table type, you'll need to do connection.commit() before closing the connection, or else none of your changes will be written to the database.

Comment: Man, this place is the best. Thanks Michael